# how to calculate enthalpy and internal energy in relation to heat capacities?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I remember that $\mathrm du=c\mathrm dT$ and $\mathrm dh=c\mathrm dT$ with $c$ being two different heat capacities, but I can't find anything about it, any help?

Comment: See the $C_V$ and $C_P$ terms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Thermodynamic_relations_and_definition_of_heat_capacity)

Comment: Good but dH=dU+d(PV)=dU+PdV+VdP. How do they say dH=dQ+VdP?

Comment: $dh=du+pdv+vdp$ , $du=\delta q-\delta w$ , $\delta w=pdv$ . So, we have: $dh=\delta q+vdp$

Comment: @lucas, good but you know why I asked that question? you know what is tricky about it? that you use one equation (dw=pdv) that is valid in very specific circumstances (p=const) and you blend it with an equation that works in ANY circumstances (dh=du+pdv+vdp)! I am not an idiot, I could do easily what you did, but I have this objection!

Comment: I am sorry if I bothered you dear ergon. I didn't want to make you upset, believe me. But as I know, $\delta w=pdv$ is valid for all cases.

Comment: $w=p\Delta v$ is valid for constant pressure.

Comment: ah yeah true cool